# How to add checkbox in php to the data retrieved from the database

Tags: php, html

I have created a database. In that database I have created a table. Then I wrote below code to retrieve the data from the created table. I retrieved all the elements that are present in the table. Now I want to add checkbox to all the rows of retrieved column. Can anyone help me out please and suggest the changes in the below code.

```
<?php
    // Check connection
    if ($link === false) {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Attempt select query execution
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fruits";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
           echo "<table>";
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<th>PID</th>";
           echo "<th>Fruit Name</th>";
           echo "<th>Quantity(Kgs)</th>";
           echo "<th>Price</th>";
           echo "</tr>";
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['PID'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Fruit Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity(Kgs)'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["submitted"] . "<td><input type ='checkbox' value = '" . $row['PID '] . "'PID = '" . $row['PID '] . "'> </td></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else {
            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you *are* adding a checkbox.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You can't nest `<td>`'s like you've done for the checkbox. If you have opened one, close it before opening another one.

Comment: Do you *really need* `*`?

Comment: You might also want to make sure that you have an equal amount of `th` and `td`, or use `colspan` to fix that. You should read up on how to use HTML tables: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: if you add checkbox then change this
 echo "<td><input type ='checkbox'            
value='".$row['PID']."'PID='".$row['PID']."'></td>";
if you add label then 
<td><label>$row["submitted"]</label><input type ='checkbox'            
value='".$row['PID']."'PID='".$row['PID']."'></td>";

Answer (score 0):

check this code i think it will work

```
<?php 
// Check connection
 if($link === false){
 die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

 // Attempt select query execution
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM fruits";
 if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>PID</th>
        <th>Fruit Name</th>
        <th>Quantity(Kgs)</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['PID']?></td>
       <td><?=$row['Fruit Name']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['Quantity(Kgs)'] ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['Price']?></td>
        <td><?=$row["submitted"]?><input type ='checkbox'            
      value="<?=$row['PID']?>" PID="<?=$row['PID']?>"></td>
      </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
<?php // Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
 echo "No records matching your query were found.";
 }
 } else{
  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 }

 // Close connection
 mysqli_close($link);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the while loop in your code. Try using this.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

     echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['PID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Fruit Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity(Kgs)'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row["submitted"]. "<input type ='checkbox' value=" .$row["PID"]. "></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

 }
```